# Layout constraints are shown in orange color in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am creating a quiz app, so there is a table view and there is a cell, and inside the cell there is a full size label and under that four full size buttons.

I have added constraints on all four sides for all the five elements as below

```
       8
       |
 20 --- ---20
       |
       8
```

The color of the constraint lines above and below 8 (single vertical lines in the above example), are showing in orange color, rest constraints are in blue color in the storyboard.

I am not able to make the orange constraints to blue, i have tried a lot of things. 
Please suggest what should i try next. 
Or 
is that even the problem to start with?

My real problem is that multiline title of my buttons are exceeding the limits of the button. 
(Ok let me try to explain more, (please picture this), i have put a black border of 1px around the buttons and the title of the button prints outside the border line of the button whenever they are multiline).

Sorry no pics uploaded, not allowed yet.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to fully understand without a picture of your Storyboard.
Based on my experience of a typical issue which happens often, probably you initially put the label in the view, then created the four constraints (top/left/right/bottom) and then you moved the label up or down. In such case your vertical constraints don't match with the original one that were set for you by Storyboard. Normally other than the orange lines you should see two orange balloons with the number of the pixel difference between what is expected and what you have.
Also try in XCode the menu Editor --> Risolve Auto Layout issues: this will change the layout to fix the issues and so you can understand the difference. You can see the list of issues also by clicking at the yellow (or red) right arrow put in the top-right corner of your Scene in the storyboard (see attached image).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, which is the best option to select from under "Resolve auto layout issues" menu? Sorry, i am new to xcode.

Comment: This is up to you. If you like what you see in the screen, then select "update constraints", if you prefer to keep your constraints then select "update frames". Before doing that however double check that all your constraints are effectively required.